# "Unexpected end of input" in javascript program

Tags: javascript, factorial

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
</title>

<script>
var n = 2;
var days = 365;

function factorial() {
        var result = 1;
        for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            result *= i
      }
       return result;
    }  

var theNumber = function baseExponent (base, exponent) {
    var number = 1;
    for (i=0; i < exponent; i++) {
        var number = base * number;
    }
    return number
}


document.write(factorial()*182)/(theNumber(days, n)
//i used the (formula n! * combination 365 2)/365^n
//i cheated a bit and just did the math for parts of this specific problem
</script>
</head>
<body>




</body>
</html>
```

i am getting an "Uncaught syntax error: unexpected end of input" for my  tag and I can't figure out why. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your "document.write" line has an unmatched open paren.

Comment: Thanks. missed that. Now I am getting an answer but it is the wrong one. Any idea what might be wrong with my syntax?

Comment: The answer I'm getting for your calculation is 0.0027322. But I think you messed up when you "cheated". (combination 365 2) should be `365!/(2!*(365-2)!)` = `365*364/2` = `66430`. Also, I'd suggest using Math.pow(365, 2) instead of what you're doing, and writing a factorial function where you pass n in as an argument.

Comment: solved it with this..function factorial(people) {
        var result = 1;
        for (i = 1; i < people; i++) {
            result = (result * ((365-i)/365))
      }
       return result;
    }  
    
document.write(1 - factorial(25))